# How to pass data from model in a multidimensional array

Tags: php, sql, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array

I want to get the data of the '$quantity' array without repeating the before index values.In the below code there is a repeating of before index values

```
$sql="select 
    tou.retailer_code,tou.retailer_name, tso.added_date,tso.sales_order_code,tsohfi.id_sales_order
     from
    tbl_sales_order_has_free_item tsohfi
    inner join 
    tbl_sales_order tso on
    tsohfi.id_sales_order=tso.id_sales_order
    inner join
    tbl_outlet_has_route tohr on 
    tso.id_outlet_has_route=tohr.id_outlet_has_route
    inner join
    tbl_outlet tou on
    tou.id_outlet=tohr.outlet_id
    inner join
    tbl_product tp on
    tp.product_id=tsohfi.product_id
    where tso.status=1 {$root}{$sales_date}
    group by tsohfi.id_sales_order
    ";  
  $free_sql = $this->db->mod_select($sql);
  foreach($free_sql as $value){

      $sql2="select 
            product_id,qty
            from
            tbl_sales_order_has_free_item
            where id_sales_order= $value->id_sales_order";

     $quantity_sql=$this->db->mod_select($sql2);

     foreach ($quantity_sql as $row)
    {

        $quantity[] = array(
                'product_id' => $row->product_id,
                'quantity' => $row->qty
              );
             } 


            $item_array[]=array(
            'retailer_code' => $value->retailer_code,
            'retailer_name' => $value->retailer_name,
            'added_date' => $value->added_date,
            'sales_order_code'=>$value->sales_order_code,
            'id_sales_order'=>$value->id_sales_order,
            'quantity'=>$quantity
               );
               }

      return $item_array;
```

Output of the repeating loop
I want to get the [0] value 1st and [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PAyHI.png) values 2nd and [2] values in 3rd etc

Comment: Post the expected output along with the relevant input

Comment: I assume `$quantity_sql` is array valued? Have you tried: `$quantity_sql[0]` for the first row?

Comment: 1->5
2->2,3,4
3->1,7

current output
5
5,2,3,4
5,2,3,4,1,7